# Tunnel MongoDB ReplicaSet using Ngrok

Tags: mongodb, ngrok

I have a replicaSet which consists of three databases running locally on an Ubuntu virtual machine with the following configuration
[image: ReplicaSet Configuration]

As seen above, I have three databases hosted on ports `27018`, `27019`, and `27020`. All having the same host name. They are all up and running and below is the output of `rs.status()`

```
{
  set: 'Dist',
  date: ISODate("2022-06-24T01:07:36.657Z"),
  myState: 1,
  term: Long("24"),
  syncSourceHost: '',
  syncSourceId: -1,
  heartbeatIntervalMillis: Long("2000"),
  majorityVoteCount: 2,
  writeMajorityCount: 2,
  votingMembersCount: 3,
  writableVotingMembersCount: 3,
  optimes: {
    lastCommittedOpTime: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1656032848, i: 1 }), t: Long("24") },
    lastCommittedWallTime: ISODate("2022-06-24T01:07:28.662Z"),
    readConcernMajorityOpTime: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1656032848, i: 1 }), t: Long("24") },
    appliedOpTime: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1656032848, i: 1 }), t: Long("24") },
    durableOpTime: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1656032848, i: 1 }), t: Long("24") },
    lastAppliedWallTime: ISODate("2022-06-24T01:07:28.662Z"),
    lastDurableWallTime: ISODate("2022-06-24T01:07:28.662Z")
  },
  lastStableRecoveryTimestamp: Timestamp({ t: 1656032848, i: 1 }),
  electionCandidateMetrics: {
    lastElectionReason: 'electionTimeout',
    lastElectionDate: ISODate("2022-06-23T23:45:44.849Z"),
    electionTerm: Long("24"),
    lastCommittedOpTimeAtElection: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 0, i: 0 }), t: Long("-1") },
    lastSeenOpTimeAtElection: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1656027744, i: 1 }), t: Long("21") },
    numVotesNeeded: 2,
    priorityAtElection: 1,
    electionTimeoutMillis: Long("10000"),
    numCatchUpOps: Long("0"),
    newTermStartDate: ISODate("2022-06-23T23:45:44.968Z"),
    wMajorityWriteAvailabilityDate: ISODate("2022-06-23T23:45:47.178Z")
  },
  electionParticipantMetrics: {
    votedForCandidate: false,
    electionTerm: Long("23"),
    lastVoteDate: ISODate("2022-06-23T23:45:36.502Z"),
    electionCandidateMemberId: 2,
    voteReason: 'already voted for another candidate (localhost:27018) this term (23)',
    lastAppliedOpTimeAtElection: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1656027744, i: 1 }), t: Long("21") },
    maxAppliedOpTimeInSet: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1656027744, i: 1 }), t: Long("21") },
    priorityAtElection: 1
  },
  members: [
    {
      _id: 0,
      name: 'localhost:27018',
      health: 1,
      state: 1,
      stateStr: 'PRIMARY',
      uptime: 5067,
      optime: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1656032848, i: 1 }), t: Long("24") },
      optimeDate: ISODate("2022-06-24T01:07:28.000Z"),
      lastAppliedWallTime: ISODate("2022-06-24T01:07:28.662Z"),
      lastDurableWallTime: ISODate("2022-06-24T01:07:28.662Z"),
      syncSourceHost: '',
      syncSourceId: -1,
      infoMessage: '',
      electionTime: Timestamp({ t: 1656027944, i: 1 }),
      electionDate: ISODate("2022-06-23T23:45:44.000Z"),
      configVersion: 1,
      configTerm: 24,
      self: true,
      lastHeartbeatMessage: ''
    },
    {
      _id: 1,
      name: 'localhost:27019',
      health: 1,
      state: 2,
      stateStr: 'SECONDARY',
      uptime: 4933,
      optime: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1656032848, i: 1 }), t: Long("24") },
      optimeDurable: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1656032848, i: 1 }), t: Long("24") },
      optimeDate: ISODate("2022-06-24T01:07:28.000Z"),
      optimeDurableDate: ISODate("2022-06-24T01:07:28.000Z"),
      lastAppliedWallTime: ISODate("2022-06-24T01:07:28.662Z"),
      lastDurableWallTime: ISODate("2022-06-24T01:07:28.662Z"),
      lastHeartbeat: ISODate("2022-06-24T01:07:36.097Z"),
      lastHeartbeatRecv: ISODate("2022-06-24T01:07:35.253Z"),
      pingMs: Long("0"),
      lastHeartbeatMessage: '',
      syncSourceHost: 'localhost:27018',
      syncSourceId: 0,
      infoMessage: '',
      configVersion: 1,
      configTerm: 24
    },
    {
      _id: 2,
      name: 'localhost:27020',
      health: 1,
      state: 2,
      stateStr: 'SECONDARY',
      uptime: 4933,
      optime: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1656032848, i: 1 }), t: Long("24") },
      optimeDurable: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1656032848, i: 1 }), t: Long("24") },
      optimeDate: ISODate("2022-06-24T01:07:28.000Z"),
      optimeDurableDate: ISODate("2022-06-24T01:07:28.000Z"),
      lastAppliedWallTime: ISODate("2022-06-24T01:07:28.662Z"),
      lastDurableWallTime: ISODate("2022-06-24T01:07:28.662Z"),
      lastHeartbeat: ISODate("2022-06-24T01:07:35.263Z"),
      lastHeartbeatRecv: ISODate("2022-06-24T01:07:35.263Z"),
      pingMs: Long("178"),
      lastHeartbeatMessage: '',
      syncSourceHost: 'localhost:27018',
      syncSourceId: 0,
      infoMessage: '',
      configVersion: 1,
      configTerm: 24
    }
  ],
  ok: 1,
  '$clusterTime': {
    clusterTime: Timestamp({ t: 1656032848, i: 1 }),
    signature: {
      hash: Binary(Buffer.from("0000000000000000000000000000000000000000", "hex"), 0),
      keyId: Long("0")
    }
  },
  operationTime: Timestamp({ t: 1656032848, i: 1 })
}
```

Now I have to deploy this replica set in order to connect to it on a `mongoose` instance in `express.js`. I tried to workaround and tcp tunnel the three ports using `ngrok` with the following `ngrok.yml` configuration

```
version: "2"
authtoken: <my token here>
tunnels:
 db1:
  proto: tcp
  addr: 27018
 db2:
  proto: tcp
  addr: 27019
 db3:
  proto: tcp
  addr: 27020
```

and ran the following command `ngrok start all`, below is the `ngrok` terminal output

[image: Ngrok terminal output]

Yet, when I tried to test the connection through MongoDB Compass on my Windows using the following URI, it gave me this error

`mongodb://2.tcp.eu.ngrok.io:17012,0.tcp.eu.ngrok.io:16864,7.tcp.eu.ngrok.io:13873/dist1?replicaSet=Dist`

[image: MongoDB Compass Error]

I don't really get what can go wrong here. I am not able to subscribe to ngrok at the mean time to have several TCP sessions. so is there any other workaround in order to deploy my own replicaSet and have full control on it (running and shutting down nodes)?

P.S: It is made for a college project.

Thanks in advance!